# Touch Doesn't Work When I Unlock the Screen

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, twrp, fastboot, motorola-moto-e

In the process of installing a new ROM on my Moto E5 Plus (not after it has been installed, even before, on the main TWRP screen for example) and after the new ROM has already been installed, the following happens: If my cell phone locks the screen, When I click on the power button and the screen turns on, the touch does not work, however, if I connect the USB cable that is connected to my Linux computer to the cell phone, the touch works again. After doing this, when I lock the cell phone again, if the cable is still connected the effect is reversed and the touch does not work until I unplug the cable, however, if I remove the cable before blocking, when I unlock the effect It will be the same as the first time, the touch will only work if you plug the cable in again.

Does anyone have any idea what it could be? Hardware problem perhaps?

EDIT 1: I noticed that this actually doesn't happen exclusively when the cable is connected to my computer, but the behavior also happens if I connect the cell phone to the charger, that is, this happens when the cell phone is receiving power or not.

Comment: As this happens directly after installing a new ROM, a likely reason is a wrong or bugged touch driver.

Comment: How can I fix it? Can you give a tip?

Comment: Try a different ROM?

Comment: It could be ghost touch, can you turn on the Developer options and Show touches, then see if there are stuck touches even if you don't touch it?

Comment: I checked here and in fact there is no touch.

Comment: Could this be caused when I unlocked the bootloader?